# OSXの日本語キーボードでEmacsの input method thai-kesmanee が正常に動作しない事への対策

Tags: emacs, key-binding, thai

Emacs上でタイ語の入力を行うために `set-input-method 'thai-kesmanee` をしたのですが、一部の文字が英字キーボードでの文字の置換を意図しているためか正常に入力できません。

例えば﻿`﻿﻿฿`は`Shift+7`のキーで入力されるはずですがEmacsの input method では`shitt+6`で入力されます。

OSのタイ語入力を使うとEmacsのキーバインドが使えなくなります。

日本語キーボードで正常に `thai-kesmanee` を使うのに何か良い方法はありますか？